# Include statement not working with LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Trying to iron out some issues with a  an MVC project using models derived from existing database tables the developer built, but none of those tables has its relationships set up (they all have primary keys, just no relationships). As such the project uses ViewModels to get some things done when more than one table is needed.

I'm attempting to get around this by adding the necessary items to relate two of the tables.

Table One's POCO:

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class Table_One
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public short ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Name")]
        public string NAME { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Owner")]
        public string OWNER { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Property")]
        public Nullable<decimal> PROPERTY { get; set; }

        public virtual Table_Two Table_Two { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Table Two's POCO:

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class Table_Two
    {
        public Table_Two()
        {
            this.Table_One = new HashSet<Table_One>();
        }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public short ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Property")]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string Property { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Table_One> Table_One { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Were these tables set up with their relationships, they'd be joined on the Property values (I've sanitized the table names and properties). As far as I can tell I've set things up to mirror the way another project I've been working on, which has tables that are related, has been set up to include the relationships, but when I run this LINQ query:

```
var model = context.Table_One.Include(t => t.Table_Two);
```

I get the following error message:

> "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'X.Table_One'
>   does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Table_Two'."

Originally these were being joined via a LINQ query using query syntax to select each of the table's properties into the ViewModel's properties.

I've tried removing the include, but that doesn't gel with other code in the controller. I've tried changing the ICollection to an IList to no avail. I've searched other answers here but none of them seem to solve the problem I'm having.

As far as I know the developer who started the project built the POCOs using a code generation tool that was run against the EDMX in the project. The only other thing I can think of at this point would be to have the developer add the relationships, then update the POCOs to pull in the updated tables via the EDMX.

I should also specify that the ID in Table_Two would be a foreign key in the PROPERTY column of Table_One.

Comment: Using EF classes as MVC model is a bad practice, you should consider creating models instead.

Comment: @user449689 I'm still a bit new to working with MVC so I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: Matt, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918938/is-it-a-bad-practice-using-model-classes-in-controller-in-mvc

Comment: @user449689 Ah, I see what you're getting at, although the article you linked is quite old and there are apparently newer ways to prevent over posting in more recent versions of MVC. http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link

Comment: @user449689 No problem, and at the same time I absolutely see what you're saying and that you can use view specific models to prevent that, but I was more familiar with handling that via the link I provided you. Still, good info to keep in mind depending on the situation. Mine may work best when it's a smaller amount of data, whereas yours if there were, say, 20 fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Include` with properties which are collections of related entities

```
var model = context.Table_Two.Include(t => t.Table_One);
```

`Include` tries to fetch collection of related entities by using joins on sql query.

If you want to load a related entity you can use lazy loading or load it using the code below

```
context.Entry(table_one).Reference(x => x.Table_Two).Load();
```

Comment: Using your second solution, with the Entry method, I get the following error: 'Project.Models.Table_One' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'. Maybe I'm following your code too literally?

Comment: `table_one` should be an instance of `Table_One`. The entry you have fetched from database already

Answer (score 0):

To rely on Entity Framework's [related entities loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx), you need to set the entities relations.

Since you said *"but none of those tables has its relationships set up"*, you won't be able to use nor lazy neither eager loading, you have to fetch the other entities by hand.

Comment: I think in this case the relation is generated by EF automatically by convention.

Comment: @dotctor how? There are no foreign keys in the models he showed us.

Comment: @Albireo In my other project, where the Include statement works, I only have the primary key setup with the Key annotation, but not one for the foreign key. Should my phrasing not be clear enough, the models in my code were generated from existing database tables, they were not coded first then used to create the database tables. We've been using the EF 5.x DbContext Generator to generate the context and models from the selected tables in the generated EDMX.

Comment: @MattD you don't have to, *if you respect the convention*. That means having an `int Id` (I *think* `int`) property and a `virtual ICollection<DependantEntity> Dependants` property in the principal entity and a `PrincipalEntity PrincipalEntityId` property (where `PrincipalEntity` is the name of the class of the principal) in the dependant entity. If you do this Entity Framework will set up the relation for you. (Probably there are a couple of variations to this, can't remember now, check the docs.)

Comment: @Albireo I don't have to...what? Generate my models from the database?

Comment: @MattD manually add the relation. If the generated model respects the convention the relations are inferred by Entity Framework, otherwise you must set them up through `EntityConfiguration<TEntity>`s in your `DbContext`'s `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: @Albireo Gotcha. Not entirely sure what that last bit means with the EntityConfiguration item, but it looks like I've got something to read up on today.

Comment: @MattD you mean https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx? If that's so, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Albireo That looks like it's for EF6 onward? Sadly we're stuck on EF5. :(